# How does bootloader(e.g. grub,lilo... ) find kernel image?

Tags: linux, kernel, bootloader

For example, if use grub to boot system, there may be lines such as

```
root (hd0,6)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4 ro root=LABEL=/
initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4.img
```

in menu.lst.

My question is:

before the kernel image is loaded into memory, I think no file system info(such as file system type, super block) which can be used to locate the kernel image in the disk exist.

So how does bootloader know the CHS of the image in the disk?

I guess that bootloader could find the super block according to "root (hd0,6)"; if so, it must blindly detect all the possible file systems and find a matching one. Is it too complicated?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask it a superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I am gonna give you an answer using Lilo like example:

The reason that you have to run /sbin/lilo after installing a new
kernel is that the LILO bootloader doesn't understand file systems it
only knows about the lower level block structure of the disk.  The
/sbin/lilo program does understand file systems, and translates the
kernel's path (i.e "/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.3") into a logical block address
ie  3-4-123) so that the LILO bootloader can find the kernel image to
load.  Effectively, this is a big hack.

Source:
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/02wi/section/bootloaders.txt

Answer (score 0):

The setup process for GRUB includes generation of

- full list of physical addresses of stage 2 file
- encoded drive number (as used with BIOS calls)
- encoded partition number (these two forms value represented as `(hd0,6)` from your example)

Stage 1 and bootstrapper of stage 2 can together use this to load full stage 2 into memory. Since that moment, stage 2 can detect FS type, activate respective read-only FS driver, read runtime config (`grub.cfg` or `menu.lst`) and proceed with following reading of `kernel`, `initrd`, etc. using FS driver.

NB this principally differs from LILO that the latter hardcodes kernel and initrd sector lists during loader installing; when booted, loader knows only sector lists but not FS structure.